# Visual Studio Code Intellisense for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am not getting autocomplete suggestions for the modules I installed via npm. It works for common modules like http though.

Example:

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());

beforeEach(() => {
web3. // no suggestions for this ??

});
```

Comment: Did you [set up a jsconfig.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig)? If not, I think that could be the problem.